# Does globalcompositeoperation=source-over work with putimagedata?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I know that ctx.globalcompositeoperation=source-over works when using drawimage but will it work with putimagedata?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer is no, composite modes does not affect `putImageData`.

Using `putImageData` works at a lower level than composition modes and context in general.

By lower level I mean it by-passes the context and the parameters it uses to alter things drawn with the other methods (translation, styles and so forth).

putImageData simply replaces the pixels directly on the resulting bitmap.

You will need to use `drawImage` to utilize composite modes and this would be faster as well as `drawImage` works directly with the bitmap memory array(s).

Comment: Since it's a lower level does that mean putImagData is faster then drawImage?

Comment: @JohnBob By lower level I mean direct access to the pixels (context works as a "mediator" between operations and pixels). `drawImage` is faster as it is filling the buffer internally in compiled code. `putImageData` still need to go through a couple of steps in JavaScript first before the (typed) array data is copied to the internal buffer.